# Short story - teenage boy (virgin) develops PK powers fuelled by frustrated lust, demonstrates for a girl, persuades her to have sex, loses powers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, psychic

Not sure when I read this - probably 80s or 90s.

The boy is all wound up with sexual frustration and starts finding he can move objects by focusing on them, e.g. causing a tin-can to shoot into the air.

The only other thing I remember is that he wonders what his sister's nipples look like when she's with her boyfriend "did they stick out like pencil erasers?". Not a very good story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Push No More](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58628) by Robert Silverberg.

I remember reading this some time in the 1970s as a teenager and it made a big impression on me. It was first published in 1972 and it's been anthologised several times since then so you could have read it in one of several different books.

The story starts:

> I push…and the shoe moves. Will you look at that? It really moves! All I have to do is give a silent inner nudge, no hands, just reaching from the core of my mind, and my old worn-out brown shoe, the left one, goes sliding slowly across the floor of my bedroom.

The protagonist is enamoured of a girl called *Cindy*, and his sexual frustration boils over into telekinetic powers. He calls his power *polting* (from *poltergeist*). The scene with the can is:

> I go up to the roof and launch another beer can to the moon, only this time I loft it a thousand feet, bring it back, kick it up even higher, bring it back, send it off a third time with a tremendous accumulated kinetic energy, and I have no doubt it’ll cleave through space.

The story ends with him sleeping with Cindy, but his powers disappear along with his virginity:

> Home. Stunned. I push…and the shoe sits there. I look up at the light fixture. Nothing. The bulb will not turn. The power is gone. What will become of me now? Commander Blaufeld, space hero! No. No. Nothing. I will drop back into the ordinary rut of mankind. I will be…a husband. I will be…an employee. And push no more. And push no more. Can I even lift my shirt and flip it to the floor? No. No. Gone. Every shred, gone. I pull the covers over my head. I put my hands to my deflowered maleness. That alone responds. There alone am I still potent. Like all the rest. Just one of the common herd, now. Let’s face it: I’ll push no more. I’m ordinary again. Fighting off tears, I coil tight against myself in the darkness, and, sweating, moaning a little, working hard, I descend numbly into the quicksand, into the first moments of the long colorless years ahead.

Comment: That's the story. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: @OmnivoreNZ I recognised your description instantly. Some stories stay with you even after 50 years. I suspect I may have identified with the protagonist more than is entirely healthy :-)